# Returning Simple Array from VBA function throws Error When assigned to Variant or Another Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variant

Following is my function :

```
Function FindMin(MinArray() As Integer) As Integer()

Dim Min As Integer
Dim Index As Integer
Dim ReturnArray(2) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Min = MinArray(0)
Index = 1

'MsgBox UBound(MinArray, 1) - 1
For i = 1 To UBound(MinArray, 1) - 1

If MinArray(i) < Min Then
Min = MinArray(i)
Index = i + 1
End If

Next i
ReturnArray(0) = Min
ReturnArray(1) = Index

'MsgBox ReturnArray(0)
FindMin = ReturnArray()

End Function
```

Here's the code that assigns it to a Variant

```
Dim IndexMin As Variant

IndexMin = FindMin(MinArray) 

Min = IndexMin(0)
Index = IndexMin(1)
```

Values are assigned while debugging the code but it get an "Object variable or With block Variable not set Runtime Error.

Any suggestions

Comment: Your code doesn't raise any errors for me and I just copy and pasted. Have another look and see if there any changes.

Comment: Where is the code that puts values in *MinArray?*

Comment: Indexmin LUST be a dynamic Array with the same type as the function returns it. Won't work with Variant in the test sub.

Answer (score 0):

The code works if **MinArray** has been initialized:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim IndexMin As Variant
    Dim MinArray(0 To 3) As Integer
    MinArray(0) = 4
    MinArray(1) = 1
    MinArray(2) = 12
    MinArray(3) = 15

    IndexMin = FindMin(MinArray)

    Min = IndexMin(0)
    Index = IndexMin(1)

    MsgBox Min & vbCrLf & Index
End Sub

Function FindMin(MinArray() As Integer) As Integer()
    Dim Min As Integer
    Dim Index As Integer
    Dim ReturnArray(2) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Min = MinArray(0)
    Index = 1

    For i = 1 To UBound(MinArray, 1) - 1
        If MinArray(i) < Min Then
            Min = MinArray(i)
            Index = i + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ReturnArray(0) = Min
    ReturnArray(1) = Index
    FindMin = ReturnArray()
End Function
```